# Ubuntu 20.04 desktop no option for minimum install

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, ubiquity

Just installing Ubuntu 20.04 desktop on a virtual machine to do some python development on, since I'm a beginner I don't want to break my main system. Creating a virtual machine(VMware) from a burnt ISO and from the ISO image, I'm not even asked for any installation options, I'd really like a light weight install but there's no option for a minimum install, I didn't even get asked to setup my hard drives just straight into installing language packs for the 3rd time, what's going on with this?

Cheers

Brett

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Option for "Minimal installation" is on the fourth screen which is titled "Install". It is right under "Normal installation".

Comment: If the suggestion from @C.S.Cameron is not so lightweight, then you can take a look at FAI - Fully Automatic Installation: https://fai-project.org/

Comment: @moep: Looks interesting, will check it out.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron np. It's a very powerfull tool, but the documentation is not that great. But afaik the comunity behind the distro GRML use it to create thier images.